# With the poisoner perk from the pickpocket tree, do you get a bounty for killing people?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the `Pickpocket` skill tree, the `Poisoner` perk allows you to plant poisons on someone and have them suffer the effects.  I was trying to determine whether to get it, so wondered if killing someone by planting a poison on them will still cause a bounty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "Reverse pickpocketing a poison using the Poisoned perk does not count
>   as a crime, even if the magical effect of the poison (e.g. "damage
>   health") would otherwise be considered a criminal act if applied any
>   other way. This makes it entirely possible to kill or weaken innocent
>   enemies, right in front of everyone, without incurring a bounty."

No, *successfully* planting enough poison on your target to kill him/her [will not create a bounty](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pickpocket) .If you fail in your attempt to reverse-pickpocket a poison onto the target, you will receive a bounty. Furthermore, if you successfully plant poison on the target, but not enough to kill them, they may hire thugs to come after you. This will not put a bounty on your character.

Comment: This doesn't work and am really disappointed! I tried several times killing an NPC with this perk in front of everyone and still ALWAYS received the standard 1000 Bounty!

Comment: It is true, actually.  After the answer was posted, I tried, and indeed I received no bounty.  The prerequisites gleaned from a lot of experimentation: (1) no one sees the pickpocket, (2) the poison cannot instantly kill the target, and (3) you have to be out of range when the person dies.  The third condition seems stupid, but that's the way it seems.  If I put a lingering health damage poison on someone and watch them die, I get a bounty, even if I wasn't caught placing it, and am invisible.  If I leave the area and come back after they're dead- no bounty.

Comment: I tested before I posted as well. To be fair, I was not aware of the range requirement (and it is a nice thing to know now)...but it sounds like you were unsuccessfully pickpocketing. Try reading into a person's answer before bashing it out-of-hand; I don't post an answer unless I'm sure it will be of use to *somebody*.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a bounty if you place a poison in someone's pocket. However,

> If you fail to attempt to place a poison, you will get a bounty.

Comment: This does not add anything new to the answer, you are just repeating (in your own words) what has already been said. if you want to answer, try to say something that hasn't already been said or has been changed recently.

Comment: That's a really weird use of a spoiler tag... Is it just in case they don't want to know the whole answer? :P

Comment: @DBS spoilers are just something that kinda spoils people which is why people give the option to spoiler to hide it.